# Should we blacklist the [inspiration], [motivation], [motivation-techniques], and [satisfaction] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request, meta-tags

I hate to be uninspiring, de-motivational, and/or dissatisfying, but I suggest we blacklist the following tags:

- [inspiration](/questions/tagged/inspiration): 19 questions, 2 of which are closed
- [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation): 60 questions, 13 of which are closed
- [motivation-techniques](/questions/tagged/motivation-techniques): 10 questions, 2 of which are closed
- [satisfaction](/questions/tagged/satisfaction): 2 questions, 1 of which is closed

These tags don't seem to have a purpose other than decorating close/migrate candidates such as these example questions:

> - [Do real programmers network and share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346722/)
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232489/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95751/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192761/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92249/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377188/

Burninate?

Comment: Ouch. Those questions are *bad*. I'm all for burnination.

Comment: They all look like metatags. Weren't those gotten rid of some time ago?

Comment: It's so beautiful, nay, *inspiring and satisfying* to see people from all over the world come together on Stack Overflow and become nationalists. Burninationalists!

Comment: @Pekka don't forget *motivating*

Comment: Okay, I used all my close votes for the day. Most of the questions I voted on were blatantly off topic and/or not constructive, and at least half were also duplicates... and yet, I was the only vote for many of them. Come on, people! If cleaning up isn't its own reward, I'll hand out a bounty or two when this question becomes eligible.

Comment: @Toomai, you're right, there's been a [policy against meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for over a year. However, actually finding instances of bad tags that need to be wiped out has been left to the community.

Comment: There's prpbably a case to be made for whether some of these questions are fit for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MPelletier, in most cases, migrating these questions would violate rule #2, "don't migrate old stuff."

Comment: @PopularDemand Where are those rules written again?

Comment: @MPelletier, all across Meta in random places, unfortunately. I only know of two rules; the other one is "don't migrate crap." For what it's worth, the answer to this question was edited by a Programmers SE mod who specifically said "Please don't automatically vote to migrate to Programmers."

Comment: @PopularDemand So, can I be forgiven for not knowing arguably ill-documented rules? ;)

Comment: @MPelletier, nothing arguable about it; those rules are definitely ill-documented. I don't think you actually did anything wrong, but you are welcome to consider yourself forgiven from my point of view.

Comment: Ignore them—they'll go away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Since the question is marked "completed," this answer is no longer being actively maintained, but it will still be updated occasionally.

This "answer" is for keeping track of tags that need cleanup. Feel free to add more yourself! **Please try to sort the list so that questions with the most unexpired close votes are at the top.**

Note that some of these tags have both on-topic and off-topic meanings, and some posts may need edits/retags instead of close votes. That said, if you do vote to close, please **don't** immediately retag; that way, it'll be easier for other close voters to find the bad apples.

Please also **don't** automatically vote to migrate to Programmers (or any other site). There's a very good chance these questions will be unwanted over there as well.

Want to discuss closure- or posse-related matters? Use the [*posse comitatus* chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/regulator-headquarters).

- [touch-typing](/questions/tagged/touch-typing) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[touch-typing]+closed%3A0)

  - **16** unclosed questions remain
- [ergonomics](/questions/tagged/ergonomics) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ergonomics]+closed%3A0)

  - **24** unclosed questions remain
- [video-tutorials](/questions/tagged/video-tutorials) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[video-tutorials]+closed%3A0)

  - **43** unclosed questions remain
- [exercise](/questions/tagged/exercise) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[exercise]+closed%3A0)

  - some of these are about exercises as in homework, not exercises as in stretching
  - **49** unclosed questions remain
- [work-environment](/questions/tagged/work-environment) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[work-environment]+closed%3A0)

  - **49** unclosed questions remain

The following tags have literally hundreds of unclosed questions each. It'll be impressive if we even get to them.

- [typing](/questions/tagged/typing) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[typing]+closed%3A0)

  - some of these are about data types, as opposed to the physical act of typing on a keyboard
- [tips-and-tricks](/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[tips-and-tricks]+closed%3A0)
- [productivity](/questions/tagged/productivity) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[productivity]+closed%3A0)
- [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jobs]+closed%3A0)
- [office](/questions/tagged/office) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[office]+closed%3A0)

  - some of these are about working with Microsoft Office, OpenOffice, &c.
- [management](/questions/tagged/management) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[management]+closed%3A0)
- [self-improvement](/questions/tagged/self-improvement) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[self-improvement]+closed%3A0)

  - See also [Burninate the [self-improvement] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110382/burninate-the-self-improvement-tag)
- [tutorials](/questions/tagged/tutorials) questions [that are not already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[tutorials]+closed%3A0)

---

We're completely done with the following tags. Good job! They should probably be considered for blacklisting if they ever return.

*These tags have not been used in over 24 hours, and therefore have been automatically deleted:*

[motivation-techniques](/questions/tagged/motivation-techniques), [satisfaction](/questions/tagged/satisfaction), [glasses](/questions/tagged/glasses), [stress-release](/questions/tagged/stress-release), [feature-creep](/questions/tagged/feature-creep), [expectation](/questions/tagged/expectation), [chair](/questions/tagged/chair), [mental-health](/questions/tagged/mental-health), [procrastination](/questions/tagged/procrastination), [junior-programmer](/questions/tagged/junior-programmer), [frustration](/questions/tagged/frustration), [work-habits](/questions/tagged/work-habits), [job-satisfaction](/questions/tagged/job-satisfaction), [programmer-efficiency](/questions/tagged/programmer-efficiency), [inspiration](/questions/tagged/inspiration), [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation), [in-the-zone](/questions/tagged/in-the-zone), [rsi](/questions/tagged/rsi), [health](/questions/tagged/health), [breaks](/questions/tagged/breaks)

*These tags still exist, but contain only closed questions:*

[desk](/questions/tagged/desk), [carpal-tunnel](/questions/tagged/carpal-tunnel), [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development), [working-conditions](/questions/tagged/working-conditions)

Comment: *Dealing with Apathy* hey, I was reading that!

Comment: I'll return tomorrow to dole out more justice.

Comment: Most useful. I've run out of votes for today. More work for tomorrow. Lets hope people aren't voting to migrate these to Programmers. The ones I looked at would be off topic/not constructive over there as well

Comment: Looks like all the [tag:inspiration] and [tag:satisfaction] tagged posts are now closed.

Comment: Well, in some cases [the tag was simply removed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/346722/revisions).

Comment: I added close votes and subtracted the tag. At least we have less instances of the stupid tag.

Comment: Can we add [programmer-efficiency] to this auto da fe?

Comment: @Rosinante - removing the tag makes it more difficult for others to find the questions again

Comment: @ChrisF I realized that belatedly.

Comment: This [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1266/per-tag-close-rate) seems to provide some more good candidates.

Comment: @Brian: wow, that's a very helpful query.

Comment: God do I hate [tips-and-tricks], it's been copied to a lot of the Stack Exchanges too. Some of these tags deserve network-wide blacklisting.

Comment: I'm doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469755/advice-needed-on-best-and-most-efficient-practices-with-developing-google-apps). Is it safe to say I'm not [Doing It Wrong(tm)](http://www.doingitwrong.com/)?