# Burninate the [self-improvement] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-block-request, clean-up, meta-tags

[self-improvement](/questions/tagged/self-improvement) has 683 questions, 117 of which are closed.

Examples:

> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140774/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833897/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434554/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230171/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852042/
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852808/

This seems to be yet another meta-tag, and thus at best unnecessary/redundant. But I wouldn't want to be too hasty... is there any valid non-meta use for this tag, or can we burninate it?

**bump** please help close or edit these questions.

Comment: How else would I tag my question about improving the Self language?

Comment: Questions about self-improvement appear to be relevant on http://productivity.stackexchange.com/, but not on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I think those kind of questions are better for Programmers, the tag [self-improvement](/questions/tagged/self-improvement) is certainly appropriate for them.  For some, it may be the **only** appropriate tag.

I guess the question should be "What else would you tag them with"?

Comment: Yeah, well... that's the thing. I guess I don't think most, if any of [these posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2004/posts-tagged-only-with-self-improvement) belong on Stack Overflow. I don't know what would happen to these if the tag were to be done away with, but I think in most cases that is not a huge concern if they're fodder for closing/deletion anyway.

Comment: I agree, most don't belong, but it was determined that many "old, popular" questions would be allowed to stick around.  Therefore, they'll need to be tagged with something appropriate as long as they're here.

Comment: OK, I see. I suppose there is some work to be done if this tag is to be blacklisted. Aside: is there a metric by which we can identify the old questions that will stay?

Comment: It's pretty subjective.  I vote to close some and protect others, but I wouldn't delete much that had a fair number of votes.

Comment: btw a lot of [self-improvement questions at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-improvement) seem to be getting closed as well. Just in case if migration is considered, [please don't use Programmers as a toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: [untagged] as previously discussed.

Comment: The only purpose for [untagged] is to be a pointer to be retagged.  I've done lots of retagging of [untagged] questions from burninated tags.

Comment: It seems that post that use the code-kata tag usually include this tag as well.  It is also common with the teach tag too.  Those two tag help me with searched, with this tag does not.  I have added it to post before just to cover bases, but have never searched on it.  It is just to vague.