# Add "tutorial" to the list of low-quality question smells

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

Lots of questions coming across on a regular basis looking for a "good tutorial" for technology XY or Z.

Can this be added to the algorithm that smells out questions that don't "meet our quality standards?"

Comment: Hmm, I'm mixed on this. On the one hand, yeah. On the other hand, asking for a tutorial is not *always* entirely wrong. I agree that "I want to do `insert incredibly complex and multi-faceted task that takes weeks of careful architecting here` does anybody know a tutorial?!?!" type questions need to be burninated though

Comment: @Pekka: Rep limit?

Comment: yeah, that might work.

Comment: What's an example of a good tutorial question? 99% of the ones I see are "please tell me where a good tutorial is" which is a "List of X" and therefore not constructive. The remaining percent is "please write a tutorial for me in an answer," which is more in the spirit of the site but still not really a specific [site topic here] question. @Pekka

Comment: @Pop I'm fairly sure I've seen some I deemed worthy of staying on the site, but I can't think of a live example. However, a question could also be *about* an existing tutorial - those are rare, but often very good because somebody is actually engaging with what they're learning.

Comment: @Pekka, very good second point, but I don't think that's what Won'tಠ_ಠ was addressing.

Comment: @Pop I agree, but how would one keep one apart from another in an automated filter?

Comment: Is there a great answer containing lists of tutorials for various different things? then redirect people to that list?

Comment: I hope not, @DanBeale. Such a list would be hard to search for (people search for "good tutorial for X," not "good tutorials"), hard to navigate and hard to maintain. If there's one place such a list might belong, it's the `[tutorials]` tag wiki, but that tag should really be destroyed per the "no meta tags" policy. I'll add it to [the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110372/should-we-blacklist-the-inspiration-motivation-motivation-techniques-an) soon.

Comment: WHO DOWNVOTED AND DIDN'T LEAVE A COMMENT!?!  I AM GOING AWAY AND NEVER COMING BACK YOU ALL ARE STINKY!