# How is this not "Off Topic"?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

How did this question survive becoming closed as *off-topic*?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397499/tendonitis-in-my-wrist

It isn't a coding question. It even managed a total score of +14. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You missed that it's more than 3 years old.

Comment: It's old; back in 2008 a lot of questions that were only tangentially related to programming were accepted. It would be shut down in a second if it were posted today, and will be closed shortly thanks to you posting it here.

Comment: Off topic for Programmers.SE [/proactive]

Comment: Seeing as almost every other question that is linked to from that question is either closed or deleted...

Comment: Migrate to PSE—too late, my joke's ruined by Yannis >:-O

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, though - the `health` tag is pretty much a cornucopia of close and delete fodder!

Comment: Unbelievable. I've tried to get rid of that question multiple times in the past and never succeeded (remember [this cleanup posse, anyone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110390/131713)). Nice work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's now closed, but to answer your question that question has been inactive for 2 years, so not many people have seen it.

[image: Inactive]

Questions that have been inactive for that long won't get closed until someone either flags it or brings it up here on Meta.

Comment: So what I've done here is OK as an informal maintenance process? I don't plan to get militant and spend hours of my day doing so. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Yuck Better than okay, it's really the process we use.  :)  Flagging would be even better, since then only one moderator close vote would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the date - a few months after SO was born. Stack Overflow used to be a somewhat different place, that brooked a broader range of "programming-related" questions. Ask a question like this today, and watch it get shot down in a hail of down and close votes.

When I happen on questions like this today, I vote to close it. I don't downvote it, because that feels unnecessarily punitive - this question was considered acceptable a few years ago.

You might also consider flagging it, asking a moderator to mark it up with an ["historical significance" banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99122/130268) (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)) as a way to warn other users from using that question as an example.

Comment: +1 So there is no culling process? No clean-up for things that used to be tolerated but are no longer acceptable? By all rights that should be migrated. IMHO its existence serves to reinforce the (incorrect) notion that it's OK to continue asking questions similar in nature.

Comment: @Yuck, see my edit. But where would you migrate it to?

Comment: @Yuck Existence of historical questions is not an acceptable reason why a question should be allowed - See for example the notes on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2349378/33051): "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."

Comment: @Yuck There is no automated cleaning process (`/review` helps a *little*) but some of us do it manually; [there are several clean-ups in process here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/clean-up).

Comment: @Cleanupcareer-development Cool, thanks for that info.